# How PlatformTransactionManager works internally in Spring Transaction?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-aop, spring-transactions

When I try to perform a transaction.....
My code looks like this..

```
public class MyService {
    private FirstDao firstDao;
    private SecondDao secondDao;
    private SomeotherDao someotherDao;

    @Transactional
    public void firstMethod() {
        // performing some operation using firstDao
        try {
            secondMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catching the exception
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void secondMethod() {
        // performing some operation using secondDao
        // some exception throws
    }

    @Transactional
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        // some other operation using someotherDao
    }
}
```

As **AOP** is the reason behind to perform the transaction in Spring. For each operation (based on the *propagation* level) I think it is going to create a proper transaction manager like `DataSourceTransactionManager`, etc.,

In the above code when I am trying to call `firstMethod` it is internally calling the `secondMethod` in the same bean. If some exception is thrown by the `secondMethod`, it should not reflect or create an problem in committing the `firstMethod`. But if problem occurred in `secondMethod` we are not able to commit the `firstMethod` also because those are sharing the same `TransactionManager`.

But as per this thread [Why are the transactions rolled back even when propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW in second method in Spring service class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313579/why-are-the-transactions-rolled-back-even-when-propagation-propagation-requires)

My understanding is by writing the `secondMethod` in some other bean/class will resolve this problem, as same `TransactionManger` is used by both methods.

I don't think that is what happening internally. If that happens, any of the method in MyService class got the exception, all the other will also be failed.

Can some one explain how the code looks like when proxy is generated.

Here is what I am thinking..

```
public class MyService {

    PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    private FirstDao firstDao;
    private SecondDao secondDao;
    private SomeotherDao someotherDao;

    @Transactional
    public void firstMethod() {
        platformTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        // performing some operation using firstDao
        try {
            secondMethod();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catching the exception
        }

        // if no problem
        platformTransactionManager.commit(status);
        // else
        platformTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void secondMethod() {
        platformTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        // performing some operation using secondDao

        // if no problem
        platformTransactionManager.commit(status);
        // else
        platformTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void someOtherMethod() {
        platformTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
        // performing some operation using someotherDao

        // if no problem
        platformTransactionManager.commit(status);
        // else
        platformTransactionManager.rollback(status);
    }
}
```

If the above case is `true`, then when `secondMethod` throws an `Exception`, there should be no problem for the `firstMethod`. But that is not happening.

So, how the proxy code will looks like, give me some idea.

**NOTE** : I'm able to solve this problem by writing the secondMethod in other class, but want to know how `PlatformTransactionManager` manages internally.

**EDIT** : As per this [@Transactional does not work on method level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590170/transactional-does-not-work-on-method-level)
When we call `firstMethod` the the `firstDAOProxy` will start the transaction inside this method we are calling `secondMethod`, `secondDAOProxy` will start the transaction. The secondMethod propagation level is REQUIRED_NEW, there should be no problem for the `firstMethod` `firstDAOProxy`, but that is not what happening.. My `firstMethod` transaction is also failing.

Comment: @JB Nizet, modified the question, can you look into it.

Comment: Your misunderstanding comes from the fact that you think using a proxy consists in modifying the code of the methods. It doesn't. It consists in wrapping the class into another one (the proxy). So when a call comes to firstMethod, the sequence is externalMethod -> proxy.firstMethod -> myService.firstMethod -> myService.secondMethod. So the proxy doesn't intercept the call to the second method. If you put the second method in another bean, you end up with externalMethod -> proxy.firstMethod -> myService.firstMethod -> proxy.secondMethod -> otherService.secondMethod.

Comment: @JBNizet, So there will be _MyService_ and _MyService$Proxy_, two classes will be available. I thought the proxies are created for DAO's, but that is not true. Proxy is created for _Service_ classes and the _PlatformTransactionManager_ is available in _Service$Proxy_ class. It(_PlatformTransactionManager_) is responsible for managing the transactions based on the Propagation Levels available on methods in the _Service_ class. correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: proxies are created for all beans that need aspects. The transactional aspect is only one of them. Other than that, yes, you're correct.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time and detailed explanation @JBNizet